# Installing libwebsockets on OS X

Tags: c, homebrew, libwebsockets

I apologize as I’m not very good with installation/using the terminal and I’m currently stuck with my installation. I really appreciate the help. I’ve installed cmake and OpenSSL (I used Homebrew to install OpenSSL). The message I get for the error is:

```
[ 92%] Building C object
CMakeFiles/websockets_shared.dir/lib/misc/lejp.c.o

make[2]: *** No rule to make target
`/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/libssl.dylib', needed by
`lib/libwebsockets.14.dylib'.  Stop.

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

[ 93%] Building C object
CMakeFiles/websockets_shared.dir/lib/roles/http/server/lejp-conf.c.o

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/websockets_shared.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have used the “export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=...” trick as stated in the README.build file. If I do not do that then it just stops earlier in the make process with an error. I’ve looked online but everything I’ve tried hasn’t worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: libwebsockets is also in homebrew. Why not install it that way?

Comment: I actually did install libwebsockets in homebrew; I used the word install multiple times but I meant compiling it with the make file. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile it if you already installed it in homebrew?

Comment: I'm trying to make the build files. I'm not sure if it's even necessary to be honest.

Comment: What it says in the Readme.build

Comment: 3. Generate the build files (default is Make files):
```
        $ cd /path/to/src
        $ mkdir build
        $ cd build
        $ cmake ..
```

4. Finally you can build using the generated Makefile:
```
    $ make && sudo make install
```

Comment: That's for building and installing it by hand. Homebrew already did all that for you. It's installed. You can just start using it.